# Boot-Repair report url boot info file persistence

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.04.

I had a boot problem which I could fix with "Boot-Repair", Thanks God!!!

But... I forgot to write the url of the reporting Boot Info file.

1) How can I know, now, that url?

2) How much long is the time persistence of that file in that url?

Comment: It is only there for a while. If you want a new report, you can just re-run it. Boot-Repair may have recorded link in its logs. Look in /var/log/boot-repair.

Comment: Thanks a lot, "oldfred"!!! Sincerely, I wasn't interesting in that url, itself. I just want to know what was the real thing, the error cause. Now, I know where is saved the report inside my PC. Thanks a lot!!!